# VB .Net - Looping through set amount of list items

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I have a list of say 20 items. But for my design I need to ensure there is never more than 5 items per `ul`. Is there a way I can loop through the list and after every 5, start a new `ul`? Not sure if this is possible, but if you've got any alternatives let me know.

Current list:

```
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Desired Result:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list item</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is this ASP.NET or Winforms?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I'm guessing ASP.NET or at least something web since it's HTML. Unless he wants to place it in a RTB or BrowserControl...

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's ASP.NET for a site.

Comment: Is it WebForms or MVC?

Comment: MVC, sorry for not stating that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is MVC, it is pretty easy to do this in a nice and simple fashion without getting int String Builders and html within your code.

Lets say you have your page model which is an Enumerable of your data model.

You could do something like

```
@For i As Integer = 0 to Model.Count() - 1

    @IIf(i Mod 5 = 0, Html.Raw("<ul>"), "")

    @<li>@Model(i).Value</li>

    @IIf((i + 1) Mod 5 = 0, Html.Raw("</ul>"), "")

Next
```

**note** This has not been tested and been a while since I did MVC with vb.net, so might not be 100% correct

Comment: Isn't MVC all about splitting logic/calculation and the presentation of data? Normally the only loop you use in the view is a `foreach` to iterate over a data-collection.

Comment: Yeah, but you also need some sort of logic when presenting data.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to manipulate existing and rendered HTML? Because then I wouldn't use VB.NET but rather jQuery or some kind of client-side technology to manipulate your HTML. If you're composing the HTML from code to be sent to the view you can try following code:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

sb.Append("<ul>")

For i As Integer = 1 To 20 Step 1

    sb.Append("<li><a href=''>list item</a></li>")

    If (i Mod 5) = 0
        sb.Append("</ul><ul>")
    End If

Next

Dim result As String = sb.ToString()
result = result.Remove(result.LastIndexOf("<ul>"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
    Dim someItms() As String = New String() {"Lorem", "ipsum", "dolor", "sit", _
                                           "amet", "consectetur", "adipisicing", _
                                           "tempor", "incididunt", "ut", "labore", _
                                           "sunt", "in", "culpa", "qui", "officia", "deserunt", _
                                           "mollit", "anim", "id", "est", "laborum", "LASTITEM"}



    Dim myelmnts As XElement = <div></div>
    Const grpsz As Integer = 5 'numer of li's per ul
    For x As Integer = 0 To someItms.Length - 1 Step grpsz
        'get a group, note last group may or may not be full
        Dim foo As IEnumerable(Of String) = someItms.Skip(x).Take(grpsz)
        Dim ul As XElement = <ul></ul> 'define ul
        Dim li As XElement 'define li
        For Each s As String In foo 'create li's
            li = <li><a href="#"><%= s %></a></li>
            ul.Add(li) 'add to ul
        Next
        myelmnts.Add(ul) 'add completed ul to list
    Next
```